# How to make Camel not to rollback changes after splitter-component

Tags: java, file, apache-camel, splitter

I need to parse file by rows. Each row handled separatly, using splitter component. After all rows were processed I need to copy file to done_folder. All works fine if all rows were processed correctly. But if there was incorrect row then I get the following warning about rollback and file do not copy to done_folder
Warning:

```
WARN (Camel (com.company.realcardparser) thread #0 - file://project/src/test/resources/working_folder) [GenericFileOnCompletion] Rollback file strategy: org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileDeleteProcessStrategy@41a7d9e7 for file: GenericFile[237file09062012-qa.csv]
```

My camel config:

```
 <camelContext id="com.company.realcardparser" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" trace="true">
        <routeContextRef ref="idtProxyRoute"/>
        <endpoint id="fileParserInputEndPoint" uri="file:${idt.proxy.real.card.parser.folder.test.input}?delete=true&amp;readLock=${idt.proxy.real.card.parser.readLock}&amp;readLockCheckInterval=${idt.proxy.real.card.parser.readLockCheckInterval}&amp;readLockTimeout=${idt.proxy.real.card.parser.readLockTimeout}&amp;delay=${idt.proxy.real.card.parser.delay}"/>
        <endpoint id="fileParserOutputEndPoint" uri="file:${idt.proxy.real.card.parser.folder.test.output}"/>
        <endpoint id="fileParserOutputFailedEndPoint" uri="file:${idt.proxy.real.card.parser.folder.test.output.failed}"/>
    </camelContext>
    <bean id="idtTxRequired" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
        <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW"/>
    </bean>

    <routeContext id="idtProxyRoute" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="idtRealCardParserRoute">
            <from ref="fileParserInputEndPoint"/>
            <transacted ref="idtTxRequired"/>
            <split>
                <method bean="realCardParser" method="handle"/>
                <to uri="bean:realCardFinalizer"/>
            </split>
            <to ref="fileParserOutputEndPoint"/>
        </route>
    </routeContext>
```

How to make camel ignore exceptions? I tried to surround splitter with try/catch block but it didn't help.

Comment: I desided to not use splitter and handle all rows manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claus Ibsen's answer directed me in the right path. However, it took me a  little while to figure out how to do it.

```
onException(Exception.class)
        .process(new Processor() {

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            // place to add logic to handle exception
            Throwable caught = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, 
                    Throwable.class);
            logger.error("FATAL ERROR - ", caught);
        }
    })
    .handled(true); // if I don't give handled(true), it will keep reprocessing the file again and again.


    from("file:" + pathToFile + "?noop=true")
    // rest of the route
```

http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html - explains more ways for error handling.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the try .. catch block inside the splitter. I assume the exception happens in your the logic thats executed inside the splitter.

An alternative is to use onException and handle the exception.